# Cannot ping localhost

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

This is a physical Dell Windows 2008 R2 SP1 server, I have this IP configuration:
[image]

I can ping 127.0.0.1

[image]

But I cannot ping any other computers. I cannot ping the network cards itself IPs.

[image]
[image]

I had reset the winsock and the ipv4 and ipv6 stack and still doesnt work. I don't have any firewall but the Windows one. It was working. It had Forefront TMG, i though it was the culprit so i totally uninstalled it.

¿Wha do you think?

Comment: For your company's sake, I wouldn't recommend giving out your private internal IP and domain information!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the fix. Uninstall the network cards and reinstall them. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you either have a very restrictive Windows firewall, or you have a loose or unplugged network cable.

Answer (score 0):

The most common culprit is that you're not running the command prompt as Administrator.  Windows Server 2008 R2 is really touchy about ping from the command prompt if you're not running elevated.

Presuming you've already tried that:

Is the Windows Firewall on?  Have you checked the rules to make sure that it's allowing traffic?  Have you checked the network cable to the device?  Do you see linklight?  Have you 
tried swapping the port on the switch?

Comment: differences with ping with UAC and without it? I dont think so..

Thanks @Drifpeasant!

Comment: You'd be surprised.  It's a very odd behavior, but I've seen it many, many times with 2k8R2